# Loader Jquery 3.2.1 / Bootstrap 4.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap-4, jquery-3

```
<style>
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('load.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}
</style>
```

En body:

```
<div class="loader">

<script type="text/javascript">
    //  Jquery 3.x
    $(window).on('load', function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
    });
</script>
```

No logro en hacerlo funcionar en la versión 3.
Gracias

Edito:
La idea es cargar una animación mientras carga el contenido de la web. (un loader)

La animación debe desaparecer al cargar la web.
Con la versión 1.x no tenia problemas, al migrar a la version 3.x e ir adaptando el contenido, algunas cosas funcionas otras no.

Comment: Te recomiendo pases por el **[Help]** . Te ayudará a hacer una pregunta más concisa. ¿Qué es exactamente lo que no funciona? Error que te da...

Comment: Aquí tuvieron el mismo problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784564/jquery-gif-loader-doesnt-fade-out

Comment: Que es lo que no lográs? Por qué usar un bacground para introducir el loader y luego lo quitas? no entiendo que quieres hacer. Si pones el loader como fondo, no tiene sentido usar el z-index: 9999; ni el position. <style>
.loader { position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 9999; display:flex;
}
</style>
<div class="loader" id="loader"> <img src='image.gif'>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> // Jquery 3.x $(window).on('load', function() { $(".loader").fadeOut("slow"); }); Prueba de este modo a ver. Si te va mejor ahora no puedo probarlo pero vamos deberia fu

Comment: Edito:
La idea es cargar una animación mientras carga el contenido de la web. (un loader)

La animación debe desaparecer al cargar la web.
Con la versión 1.x no tenia problemas, al migrar a la version 3.x e ir adaptando el contenido, algunas cosas funcionas otras no.

Comment: ¿Dónde incluyes jQuery 3? ¿Dónde va el código de `$(window).load`? Por favor, lee [ask] y edita la pregunta para crear un [mcve] y que podamos ver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí se carga un loader haciendo uso de jquery 3.2.1 Todo funciona correctamente, luego el fallo de tu aplicación no está en el uso de jquery 3.2.1 para esto.

```js
 $(window).on('load', function() { 
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
 });
```

```css
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/09b24e31234507.564a1d23c07b4.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}

La version 3 de jquery funciona en este ejemplo.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader">
```